# Bar plots with variable bases (intensive and extensive variables at once)

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, barplot

Is there a particular name for bar plots, in which bars are rectangular, with unequal bases?

That is:

- width represents size (e.g. population),
- height represents intensive variable (e.g. CO$_2$ emission per capita),
- area represents extensive variable (e.g. total CO$_2$ emission).

Example (from [David JC MacKay, "Sustainable Energy - without the hot air", page 14](http://www.withouthotair.com/c1/page_14.shtml)):

[image: CO2 emission rate by country]

In the same vein: [this](http://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/ar4/wg3/en/figure-1-4.html) and [that](http://manicbeancounter.com/2015/01/25/global-emissions-reductions-targets-for-cop21-paris-2015/).
Another one: "Real GDP Per Capita and Shares of Global Population" ([found here](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2014/08/mind-your-qs.html)):

[image]

I find these plots immensely useful, as they show both the local effect (is a country particularly rich, polluting, militaristic...) and the global share (of economy/pollution/military power).

I have even made one: [Research publications per capita? - Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18810/49). I care for its name both to search for examples, plotting libraries/functions etc, and to propagate this way of presenting data.

Comment: All bars are rectangular (quadrilateral with four right angles)! What's a little unusual here are the varying (unequal) bar widths. Plotting cumulative shares like this is perhaps more commonly done using a Lorenz curve, which in turn is a kind of P-P (probability-probability) plot. You have here  discrete versions with several bars identified. I don't know that this has, or really needs, a distinctive name. Your second graph is closer to a Lorenz curve; the first has extra structure given by grouping.

Comment: @NickCox I missed "uneven base" (fixed). Thanks for brining [Lorenz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve) (I know it, but I was not thinking about it as bar plots from this question can, but don't have to be, ordered).

Comment: Small corrections: In English we would not say "uneven"; that's for surfaces not quite flat or smooth. It's  Lorenz: Lorentz was a different person altogether. Key point: You are correct: bar charts with touching unequal width bars do not have to be ordered. But they are not of much use or interest without an ordering of some kind.

Comment: @NickCox Lorenz - fixed (I can never remember, same Schwar(t)z). Well, there are other orderings, which make sense (e.g. as in the example 1); or there may be no ordering if there are only a few values. Is "variable bases" OK?

Comment: My suggestion on wording remains varying or unequal bar widths. As the word "varying" or "variable" is likely to occur often in any report, as a matter of style "unequal" might be preferred. (Schwartz for Schwarz is indeed a very common mistake, whether it is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or Schwarz's BIC.)

Comment: Kaiser Fung points out the shortcomings of that GDP chart in his [junkcharts blog](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2014/08/world-bank-fails-to-lead-the-way-in-dataviz.html) and a [follow-up post](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2014/08/mind-your-qs.html).

Comment: @xan Each data visualization method has its strong and weak parts. True - comparing at exact areas is difficult. Yet, for the alternative it's hard to sum things (e.g. in the cascade plot it is simple to estimate Europe vs Africa; for scatter plots - it isn't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently they are called **cascade charts**, see:

- [Variable Width Column Charts (Cascade Charts)](http://peltiertech.com/variable-width-column-charts/) - Excel
- [The Cascade Chart Creator add-in for Microsoft Excel](https://www.add-ins.com/cascade_charts.htm)
- [Cascade chart (graph with variable width bars) - Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1295525-cascade-chart-graph-with-variable-width-bars)

As a bonus, [ggplot2: Variable Width Column Chart](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2-variable-width-column-chart/).

However, sometimes *cascade chart* is used as a synonymous of *waterfall chart* (which is a different thing from the discussed above), see e.g.:

- [Creating a Waterfall (Cascade) Chart - FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/chart-guide/waterfall-or-cascade-chart/creating-a-waterfall-or-cascade-chart.html)

In any case, judging for length I needed to get this answer, this name may be not that popular even among people creating similar bar plots (and perhaps a descriptive way may be better).

As was pointed out by @NickCox, if bars are sorted by their height, it is a discrete variant of the [Lorenz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve).

Comment: I found three quite different meanings for waterfall plot or chart in a search a while back. Picturesque name, inconstant interpretation.